# C code to move file to trash

Tags: c

I'm trying to remove a file in a C program, but when I use the remove() function it completely removes the file and not sending it to the trash. How can I remove a file to trash?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most probably there is no system-independent way of doing this. Which operating system (and desktop environment) does it have to work on?

Comment: oh ok sounds logical. It has to work on Mac - mavericks

Comment: look http://www.freedesktop.org/wiki/Specifications/trash-spec/

Answer (score 1):

On Mac OS, you should use the [`recycleURLs:completionHandler:`](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/ApplicationKit/Classes/NSWorkspace_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSWorkspace/recycleURLs%3acompletionHandler%3a) method in `NSWorkspace`.

Answer (score 1):

Almost every operating system provides an API to perform a soft delete by moving files to the trash. Unfortunately there is no unified specification on how a trash / recycling bin should work. On Windows you can use `IFileOperation`, macOS has the `NSFileManager` and on Linux and BSD you either use a tool that implements the [FreeDesktop.org trash specification](https://specifications.freedesktop.org/trash-spec/trashspec-1.0.html) such as `gio trash` (GNOME), `kioclient5 move` (KDE), `trash-cli` or implement your own.

Another solution is using a cross-platform library that allows to move files and directories to the trash / recycling bin like [libtrashcan](https://github.com/robertguetzkow/libtrashcan). This simplifies development because you only use a single function call without worrying about platform specific details.

Answer (score 0):

For Windows See `SHFileOperation` with `FOF_ALLOWUNDO`.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb762164.aspx

On Mac OS X, you have to call `FSMoveObjectToTrashSync` (or its async friend) from `CoreServices`.

Answer (score 0):

In linux i will do...

```
system("mv your_file.txt /home/username/.local/share/Trash/");
```

Answer (score -2):

If you are on Windows try this.

Open a Command Prompt (DOS windows) and type

```
cd \$RECYCLE.BIN
dir \a
```

and you will get a list of all the trashes of all the users in your computer.

In your program move the file to the proper trash.